# How to know whether an nvidia graphic card is installed or not?

Tags: nvidia

My terminal says:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev ff)
```

It seems to me that it is installed but can't find the control panel.

Answer (score 2):

You can see what graphic card is installed by going in **System Settings...** → **Software & Updates** and select **Additional Drivers** tab:
[image: Additional Drivers]

Comment: already did that. nothing is there in additional drivers tab

Comment: @AbhinavBhardwaj This mean that you don't have an nvidia driver.